# Nuxt redirect a static file... where the url has an extension name

Tags: redirect, nuxt.js, middleware

I want to redirect from DOMAIN/file.pdf to DOMAIN/complicated-file-name.pdf

The actual file in my static folder has name complicated-file-name.pdf. I want my user to see/download file with the complicated file name filename, but be able to get to it from a shorter path.

My app is client-side rendered and target is static.

This is with Nuxt 2.15.0.

I've tried creating a redirect using middleware. This works in the development environment, but not production environment:

`middleware/redirects.js`

```js
export default function (req, res, next) {
  const redirects = [
    {
      from: '/file.pdf',
      to: '/complicated-file-name.pdf',
    },
  ]
  const redirect = redirects.find((r) => r.from === req.url)
  if (redirect) {
    res.writeHead(301, { Location: redirect.to })
    res.end()
  } else {
    next()
  }
}
```

and in `nuxt.js.config`:

```js
...
serverMiddleware: ['~/middleware/redirects.js'],
...
```

Comment: Is it meant to be working only on initial render or later on, while using client-side navigation? Because `serverMiddleware` will be useful only in the first case. Also, where do you host your app?

Comment: @kissu Meant to work while using client-side navigation. Yes, this is something I thought might be the problem, but am not sure how to fix it. Currently I'm hosting through github pages

Comment: You cannot have SSR on Github pages. For your feature, you don't even need a serverMiddleware anyway. You could do that client-side with a `key/value`pair for `simple/complex` filenames and make a redirect to the proper file. Make a dynamic page and check the simple file, and serve the complex one with a download or open it in another tab.